# ASP.Net - manual thread not starting

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I have a web page that launches a manual thread and it works just fine.

I added a new domain to the same server and copied an updated version of my web site to it and now the thread will not start. The code that starts the thread and the class that the thread starts have not changed.

So why would the same code on different sites on the same server behave differently?

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538122/asp-net-threading-not-working-in-production#_=_) which indicates I may have a permissions issue, but trying this does not solve the issue.

I tried to find any different settings between the the sites and verified the directory permissions were identical. I can't find anything different.

That else am I missing?

Thanks for the help!
Brad

Comment: Do they run under the same User Identity in their respective AppDomain? Do they access the same resource that may cause blockage? And last didn't you got any exception?

Comment: You can change the code to log what will happen.

Comment: I am not sure how to check the User Identity of the AppDomain - I will look into that. No resource conflicts that I am aware of. No exceptions are thrown, the thread is spawned as far as my code knows, just nothing happens. I have instrumented it as much as I know how, but it is as if the thread just goes.. nowhere.

Comment: I just verified they are both in the same AppPool both using the IWAM_Plesk identity. Still not sure how to check for AppDomain Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Check the identity that the application pool runs under (see http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/).  The old site and the new one probably run under different identities.

As an aside, launching background threads from ASP.NET is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Both sites are on the same server and use the same AppPool - I think. The original one has been running problem free for 2+ years. I have not found a way to tell a site which AppPool to use (I seem to have 6 different ones on this server.) I tried changing the identities of the ones that look like the correct ones and no effect.

Comment: Just learned how to check and change AppPool location. They are both in the same AppPool.